XPath exclude child similar elements
How can I select all elements by attribute name but exclude child elements that are identical using XPath?
HTML
 <div c-store="test">
    <div c-text>Product Name</div>
    
    <div c-store="test">
        <div c-text>Product Name</div>

        <div c-store="test">
            <div c-text>Product Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Desired result
<div c-store="test">
    <div c-text>Product Name</div>
</div>

Each c-store element should not contain other similar c-store elements.

First off, "identical" should be defined better. Secondly, why must be strict to xpath and not by the help of Javascript?

This XPath,
//div[@c-store="test"][not(div[@c-store="test"])]

will select all div elements with @c-store values of "test", provided the div element has no children div elements with the same property.
